# Parsing session info between WordPress and non-WordPress

Tags: session

I have a Web App that resides in example.com (non-WordPress, completely independent databases, etc) and I have a WordPress website, website.example.com and example.com/website.

Users will never log into WordPress, but they will access the WordPress website, then log into the Web App.

The Web App stores sessions and on the Web App pages I display this to show that the user is logged in:

```
echo “<a href='#' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown'>
    Welcome, ".$_SESSION['full_name']." !</a>”;
```

How can I show this in WordPress if they change pages to the WordPress website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use javascript, loading from your app - example.com and save the relevant info in cookie. Then on the WordPress, again using javascript, loading from your app (this is important to be able to read cookie) to read value of that cookie and update the page accordingly.

Comment: Hi Ashfame, Do you have any code suggestions/examples? Thanks

Comment: Not really. But that's how something like that is done.